# Testing a network without setting number of iterations

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I have a pre-trained network with which I would like to test my data. I defined the network architecture using a .prototxt and my data layer is a custom Python Layer that receives a .txt file with the path of my data and its label, preprocess it and then feed to the network.

At the end of the network, I have a custom Python layer that get the class prediction made by the net and the label (from the first layer) and print, for example, the accuracy regarding all batches.

**I would like to run the network until all examples have passed through the net.**

However, while searching for the command to test a network, [I've found](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/interfaces.html):

```
caffe test -model architecture.prototxt -weights model.caffemodel -gpu 0 -iterations 100
```

If I don't set the -iterations, it uses the default value (50).

Does any of you know a way to run caffe test without setting the number of iterations?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you mean the number of iterations equals to 1  by "without setting the number of iterations"? In fact, you can just set `iterations` a number `n` to ensure `n*batch_size == TOTAL_NUM`, in which `TOTAL_NUM` is the number of all samples. If your memory is large enough, you can set `iterations = 1, batch_size = TOTAL_NUM` to pass all examples through the net at a time.

Comment: Yes, the way I'm doing right now is by figuring out `n`, which is `TOTAL_NUM / batch_size` and running `caffe test` passing n as an argument. But let's suppose I change the `TOTAL_NUM` (by increasing my dataset, for example)... I was hoping there was a way to run `caffe test` without determining `n` beforehand.

Comment: Maybe you can write some code to compute `n` beforehand in the script(`.bat` or `.sh`) that launches `caffe test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Caffe does not have a facility to detect that it has run exactly one **epoch** (use each input vector exactly once).  You could write a validation input routine to do that, but Caffe expects you to supply the quantity.  This way, you can generate easily comparable results for a variety of validation data sets.  However, I agree that it would be a convenient feature.

The lack of this feature might be related to its lack for training and the interstitial testing.
In training, we tune the hyper-parameters to get the most accurate model *for a given application*.  As it turns out, this is more closely dependent on **TOTAL_NUM** than on the number of epochs (given a sufficiently large training set).

With a fixed training set, we often graph accuracy (y-axis) against epochs (x-axis), because that gives tractable results as we adjust batch size.  However, if we cut the size of the training set in half, the most comparable graph would scale on **TOTAL_NUM** rather than the epoch number.

Also, by restricting the size of the test set, we avoid long waits for that feedback during training.  For instance, in training against the ImageNet data set (1.2M images), I generally test with around 1000 images, typically no more than 5 times per epoch.

Comment: Yes, but I'm referring to the test phase. I already got my model trained, but I would like to run exactly one epoch, without needing to define the number of iterations every time my test dataset changes.

Comment: Ah ... it's the same response, I'm afraid, but I'll edit my answer to match your question.  Sorry.